# PHP looping through huge text file is very slow, can you improve?

Tags: php, performance, loops

The data contained in the text file (actually a .dat) looks like:

```
LIN*1234*UP*abcde*33*0*EA
LIN*5678*UP*fghij*33*0*EA
LIN*9101*UP*klmno*33*23*EA
```

There are actually over 500,000 such lines in the file.

This is what I'm using now:

```
//retrieve file once        
$file = file_get_contents('/data.dat'); 
$file = explode('LIN', $file);

    ...some code

foreach ($list as $item) { //an array containing 10 items
     foreach($file as $line) { //checking if these items are on huge list
         $info = explode('*', $line);
         if ($line[3] == $item[0]) {
             ...do stuff...                     
             break; //stop checking if found
          }
      }         
 }
```

The problem is it runs way too slow - about 1.5 seconds of each iteration. I separately confirmed that it is not the '...do stuff...' that is impacting speed. Rather, its the search for the correct item.

How can I speed this up? Thank you.

Comment: If you want to search a 500,000 line file 10 times it's probably always going to take a long time...

Comment: Yes, although technically it's searching an array not the file. I figured there must be some array function that can help out here.

Comment: You could run a regex pass over the entire file without splitting it into an array, it depends on what you do in the `...do stuff...` section and whether you need to return the line number or other parts from the line etc. **edit** or even just a simple `strstr()` lookup for that string...

Comment: What about just using `grep`? writing the output to a file, then reading that with PHP?

Answer (score 3):

If each item is on its own line, instead of loading the whole thing in memory, it might be better to use `fgets()` instead:

```
$f = fopen('text.txt', 'rt');

while (!feof($f)) {
    $line = rtrim(fgets($f), "\r\n");
    $info = explode('*', $line);
    // etc.
}

fclose($f);
```

*PHP file streams are buffered (~8kB), so it should be decent in terms of performance.*

The other piece of logic can be rewritten like this (instead of iterating the file multiple times):

```
if (in_array($info[3], $items)) // look up $info[3] inside the array of 10 things
```

Or, if `$items` is suitably indexed:

```
if (isset($items[$info[3]])) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but fopen actually seems to have slowed it down.

Comment: @user2029890 Not sure what code you've ended up with after applying my answer :) also, if performance is *that* important you should probably use a database instead, SQLite for instance ...

Comment: @JakeGould Which is why I suggested to use `in_array()` on the inside loop instead; in fact, thinking about it now, if the keys of `$items` can be used it could be made even faster using `if isset($items[$info[3]])`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `file_get_contents`, it loads the stuff into the memory so you can only imagine how resource intensive the process may be.  Not to mention you have a nested loop, that's `(O)n^2`

You can either split the file if possible or use  `fopen`, `fgets` and `fclose` to read them line by line.

If I was you, I’d use another language like `C++` or `Go` if I really need the speeds.

Comment: Considering that the process will be mostly disk bound I doubt whether another language will be able to squeeze out more performance :)

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` loads the whole file into memory as an array & then your code acts on it. Adapting this sample code from [the official PHP `fgets` documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) should work better:

```
$handle = @fopen("test.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        $file_data = explode('LIN', $buffer);
        foreach($file_data as $line) {
            $info = explode('*', $line);
            $info = array_filter($info);
            if (!empty($info)) {
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($info);
                echo '</pre>';
            }
        }         
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

The output of the above code using your data is:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1234
    [2] => UP
    [3] => abcde
    [4] => 33
    [6] => EA

)
Array
(
    [1] => 5678
    [2] => UP
    [3] => fghij
    [4] => 33
    [6] => EA

)
Array
(
    [1] => 9101
    [2] => UP
    [3] => klmno
    [4] => 33
    [5] => 23
    [6] => EA
)
```

But still unclear about your missing code since the line that states:

```
foreach ($list as $item) { //an array containing 10 items
```

That seems to be another real choke point.